# i want to remove the hash function and use the same code to store password as varchar

Tags: php, json, hash

I have the below code from a tutorial but i want to understand its working and hence want to simplify it. I dont want the password to be stored with encryption, just plain text. what are the changes i need to make? will i need to make any changes in corresponding java file, that uses the json object/array?

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt,created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: To answer this, once a password has been hashed, it can't be converted back its originally user-entered password. Hashing is a one-way method, there's no reversal.

Comment: nope i dont want to get back the password, all i want is to simplify the code a bit, i had around 4 php files 6 java files. The tutorial had some silly bugs, fixed them and the code is running fine. But i want to simplify it. thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, password, salt,created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$password', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to modify the variable and leave out the hashing function, you also need to modify the name of the field you insert to from `encrypted_password` to `password` and since you won't be using the salt anymore, you don't insert it.

With all that being said, you must understand that hashing passwords is the number one rule of storing password, the number one rule of building web application. **YOU MUST HASH PASSWORDS FOR THE SECURITY OF YOUR USERS**

Comment: yes agreed. final version will have a hash. but first i would like to learn about it rather than just using it in my code:), will mark answered once i complete the modified code